# Constructing segmented lists by third-party contributions

Tags: list-manager, segmented-list

My client has three different segments, where contacts can subscribe to each one of them.
These subscriptions come from three separate channels, 1. Website, 2. Dynamics CRM and 3. OptinMonster.

Contacts subscribing from the website, are being processed by setting custom facets depending on what segment they would like to subscribe to (wffm takes care of that mapping).

Contacts that have subscribed by Dynamics CRM are being synchronized by DataExchange Framework.

Contacts that have subscribed by OptinMonster i'm planning on to import those to 3 separate lists, segmented by what segment they have subscribed to.

Now my question is, how would you go about targeting one specific segment, collected from all different channels?

What i have thought of myself is something like this.

1. Create a segmentation rule that looks into the custom facet i made for the website subscribers and collect contacts that have subscribed to the targeted segment.
2. Create a segmentation rule that looks into what lists that the contact are currently subscribed to. If the contact is currently subscribed to the targeted regular list from OptinMonster, add the contact to the segmented list.
3. Take advantage of the Dynamics CRM segmented rule that was installed by DataExchange to collect contacts subscribed to the targetet segment marketing list in CRM.

Combine these three rules in a new segmented list, that can be selected and used with EXM.

What do you think? Is there a smarter way?

**Update**

I forgot to add that it's version 8.2 i am working with.
Also i made a diagram that explains what i'm thinking of doing:

[image]

I am pretty sure this is the way to go.

The next part is finding a way to make the user able to unsubscribe from the different channels.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have 3 segments (client interests?) and 3 list sources (channels).  The channel is important here, only because you use different methods to capture email preferences.

[image]

I'm going to make the assumption that your email permissions are tied to the segments, not the channels.  I'm also going to make the assumption that you're importing emails from your 3 channels into specific contact lists.  Lastly, I'm going to make the assumption that you'll use EXM and List Manager to manage permissions.

If you have a custom contact facet for each of the 3 segments you can create 3 segmented lists from all contacts (all 3 channels).

[image]

The unknown part here is how you intend to manage email preferences.  There is email preference management functionality built into Sitecore 9.1.  That includes the ability to opt-out of specific lists.  Those are contact lists, not segment lists.   So, you'd need to use the **Update Subscriptions** functionality instead of the **I do not want to receive any emails from [specific list]** functionality. The opt-out of specific list functionality only works on contact lists.

Here's info on the email preference center.  https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/91/email-experience-manager/en/configuring-the-preference-center.html

Comment: I updated my question, thank you for your reply.